# Bootstrap 3 Form field not showing large on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am having a problem here with the mobile display.  I want the form input to show the input bar very large.  It shows it fine on desktop any size window I make it.  But the second I look at it on a mobile device if it is vertical the form input is no where near as large and you have to zoom to see it.  But the second I turn the phone horizontal it shows it fine.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 center-block">
            <form action="{{url_for('check')}}" method="POST">
            {{ form.url(placeholder=form.url.description, class="form-control input-lg") }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I was able to figure it out.  This was missing in the header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get a single upvote for this in 5 years. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I am surprised as well ... Thanks for saving me some hours searching for this

Answer (score 0):

You can make the input field take up the whole available width by using class `col-xs-12`.

```html
<!--- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--- personal styles should always be below Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">-->

<!--- Google  fonts-->


<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 center-block">
            <form action="{{url_for('check')}}" method="POST">
             <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="form-control input-lg" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it still shows it very small.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Both for large and small display. Also try with `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 center-block">`

Comment: I think it might be specific to the Galaxy note 2 display.  Since every site I try to use to check the responsiveness seems to show that it loads fine size

Comment: I got it posted answer.  Thank you for your help in debugging

Comment: You are welcome, next time don't miss anything and make a JSFiddle or code snippet to support your question